# Javascript/HTML5 EventListener for Multiple Buttons For-Loop -- Link to Nav's

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button, click, event-listener

So, before I paste samples of my code, I'd like to explain a bit more.

Essentially I have an information page that is organized similar to a product version differences page. Columns are "product versions" and Rows are "features". However, my rows are keywords and the other three rows are buttons the user can press to show a type of information relating to that keyword. Each keyword can have up to three types of information, but anyway...

The code for it works, however, I have 55 buttons that spans across at least 30 keywords (some keywords have more than one type of information). I already have it working with a .js file I fiddled with.

However, the script is over 350 lines long and I KNOW I can use a for loop with "addeventlistener" and have been trying to do this for the past day or so, and nothing online seems to pertain to this.

Here are the three portions of the script:

First: Creating a variable from button by its ID and another variable for the "Nav" by its ID. There are 55 of these buttons/nav combos, so 110 variables. Way too much.

Note: the "showright#" are the buttons and the "menuRight#" are the nav's

SAMPLE OF SCRIPT:

```js
var menuRight1 = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s1'),
  showRight1 = document.getElementById('showRight1'),
  menuRight2 = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s2'),
  showRight2 = document.getElementById('showRight2'),
  menuRight3 = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s3'),
  showRight3 = document.getElementById('showRight3'),
  //....continue to showright55 and menuRight55....
  //Next up is the section where we use an "onclick" for each     
  //button...so....55 of these
  showRight1.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle(this, 'active');
    classie.toggle(menuRight1, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
    disableOther('showRight1');
  };
showRight2.onclick = function() {
  classie.toggle(this, 'active');
  classie.toggle(menuRight2, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
  disableOther('showRight2');
};
//lastly, disabling the other buttons until the button clicked, is
//clicked again to disable it (prevents users from opening more than one
//'info' at once
function disableOther(button) {
    if (button !== 'showRight1') {
      classie.toggle(showRight1, 'disabled');
    }
    if (button !== 'showRight2') {
      classie.toggle(showRight2, 'disabled');
    }
    if (button !== 'showRight3') {
      classie.toggle(showRight3, 'disabled');
    }
    if (button !== 'showRight4') {
      classie.toggle(showRight4, 'disabled');
    }
  }
  //....all the way to showRight55 and menuRight55...
```

the HTML for the buttons looks like this (sample):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="spaan9">
      Keyword
    </th>
    <th class="spaan1">
      <div class="main1">
        <section>
          <!-- Class "cbp-spmenu-open" gets applied to menu -->
          <button id="showRight36" style="margin: 0px auto; position: relative;">
            Select
          </button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="spaan1">
    </th>
    <th class="spaan1">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the HTML for the nav looks like this (sample):

```html
<nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" id="cbp-spmenu-s37">
  <h3 class="text-center">
            Header Information
        </h3>
     <!--Random Information to show user here-->
</nav>
```

Basically what is happening, is that now that we've gotten the element for any nav-button combo where the button of that combo is clicked, my javascript in an external .js file will work it's magic. The 'active' bit essentially is giving the "button" a "class=active" to notify the corresponding "nav" that it's button is now active and to reveal itself. Surely I must be messing up this for loop for the eventlistener? Any insight or assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out....

Took me a bit of time though. Looks like I just needed to take a short break from it. Anyway, here is my solution.

```
 var showRightBtn = [];
    var menuRightNav = [];
    var i;
    for (var i = 1; i < 58; i++) {
        menuRightNav[i] = document.getElementById("cbp-spmenu-s" + i);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 58; i++) {
        showRightBtn[i] = document.getElementById("showRight" + i).onclick = function () {
            i = this.id.substring(9, 11); //NOTE: IMPORTANT LINE: Gets number from "activated button" and gives it to proper variables
            classie.toggle(this, 'active');
            classie.toggle(menuRightNav[i], 'cbp-spmenu-open');
            disableOther("showRight" + i);
        }
    }
    function disableOther(button) {
        //if (button == "showRight" + i) {
            //disables buttons below button clicked
            for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                classie.toggle(document.getElementById("showRight" + j), 'disabled');
            }
            //disables buttons above button clicked
            for (var j = 57; j > i; j--) {
                classie.toggle(document.getElementById("showRight" + j), 'disabled');
            }
        //}
    }
```

Reduced the script from over 700 lines, to just 27.